# Not all code path returns value in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing Cloud Functions using TypeScript. I want to call another third party API. I've created the functions as shown below.

```
export const postData= functions.https.onRequest((req, response) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return response.status(500).json({
            message: 'not allowed'
        });
    }
    else {
        let phoneNumber = req.query.phoneNumber;
        request('https://api.xyz.com/api/insertData.php?authkey=xxxxxx&userid=' + phoneNumber,
         function (error: any, respon: any, body: any) {
            console.log(body);

        })
        .then(function(xyz:any){
            return response.status(200).json({
                dataPosted: true
            })
        })
        .catch(function(error:any){
            return response.status(200).json({
                dataPosted: false
            })
        })
    }
});
```

But when I'm trying to deploy my function, it says "Not all code path returns a value". But I've returned response in both `if` & `else`.
What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Can you clarify what module the `request` object is from?  I wouldn't expect to see both a provided callback and a `.then()` call.  Either way, its your else clause that should either return a value or return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your else-field is run to finish without waiting. And in that case, it might not reach "then" or "catch". You should maybe wait for that request?

Comment: I am beginner in TS, can you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the else part is not returning anything. Shouldn't you return the request result?

```
export const postData= functions.https.onRequest((req, response) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return response.status(500).json({
            message: 'not allowed'
        });
    }
    else {
        let phoneNumber = req.query.phoneNumber;
        return request('https://api.xyz.com/api/insertData.php?authkey=xxxxxx&userid=' + phoneNumber,
         function (error: any, respon: any, body: any) {
            console.log(body);

        })
        .then(function(xyz:any){
            return response.status(200).json({
                dataPosted: true
            })
        })
        .catch(function(error:any){
            return response.status(200).json({
                dataPosted: false
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: the code is different, adding a return where it is needed. `return request(` instead of just `request(`.

Answer (score 0):

The request library you are using supports callback interfaces natively but does not return a promise.

You can use `request-promise` (https://github.com/request/request-promise) and the `rp()` method which "returns a regular Promises/A+ compliant promise" and then adapt your code as follows:

```
//......
import * as rp from 'request-promise';

export const postData = functions.https.onRequest((req, response) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return response.status(500).send('not allowed');
  } else {
    let phoneNumber = req.query.phoneNumber;

    var options = {
      url:
        'https://api.xyz.com/api/insertData.php?authkey=xxxxxx&userid=' +
        phoneNumber,
      method: 'POST'
    };

    return rp(options)
      .then(function(parsedBody: any) {
        response.send('data posted');
      })
      .catch(function(error: any) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: @SushantSomani Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?